# Keeping Only One Complete URL

Tags: java, regex

I have some content that contains text in addition to URLs in this format:

```
some text http://www.example.com/foo... <http://www.example.com/foo.html> some text
```

or this format:

```
some text http://www.example.com/bar <http://www.example.com/bar> some text
```

I need to clean it to become, respectively:

```
some text http://www.example.com/foo.html some text
```

and:

```
some text http://www.example.com/bar some text
```

Is there a way to achieve this with regular expressions?

Comment: This may help: http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks! This helped (see answer).

Comment: @mossaab I would if I didn't know the difference between a comment and an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by [using backreferences to match the same text again](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
input.replaceAll("(https?://([^ ]+))(\\.{3,3})? *<(\\1[^ ]+)>", "$4")
```